# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 7738: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to get a Python  program to extract a date from a website and copy this data to a json file. here is the part of the code which concerns the creation of the json file :

```
with open(city+'.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as file:
        json.dump(data, file ,ensure_ascii=False)

with open('citys.txt', "r") as file:
        citys = file.readlines()
```

When i try to execute the code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main3.py", line 173, in <module>
get_data_from_company(company_link['href'],city_name_id[0])
  File "main3.py", line 132, in get_data_from_company
data = json.load(file)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Python38\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
  UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 7738: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Please provide the json file, if it is too long, you can just provide the part which got error.

Comment: due to the error no file is generated

Comment: I mean the origin `{city}.json` file before you run the code.

Comment: Your traceback indicates a problem in a function which is _reading_ data from a file. The code you posted is fine, and cannot produce the error you are asking about. Please [edit] to show the _actual_ code which generates the traceback, and ideally also a minimized version of the JSON file so we can see what's there. We need to see the _actual bytes_ which represent any non-ASCII characters.  See also the guidance for providing a [mre] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Comment: no the file will be created after executing the code

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Again, you are writing the file just fine. The _reading_ code is flawed.

Comment: the code allows me to read and extract lines from a text file see the modification

Comment: The code in the question still does not match the traceback. Again, you want to provide a [mre]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You failed to specify the encoding in the second `open` call. This causes Python to use your system's default encoding, which on Windows is usually some legacy code page (in your case, code page 1252) which cannot properly handle UTF-8.

The fix is easy; specify `encoding='utf-8'` just like in the first `open` call.